# Is there an R function for recoding a column based on a modified version of another without using a loop?

Tags: r, dataframe

I'm currently working on a project that would require recoding for one field based on detection in another field as shown below. For the case in the second row, i would need to recode Col1 so that it resembles the value in Col2. After recoding such values, I would need to filter the dataset so that only rows with Col1 values found in Col2 are kept.

```
Col1     Col2 
CN234    CN234
WO/123   WO/0123
KR567    KR456
```

I have currently the following code, which is not working:

```
df$Col3= paste(str_split(df$Col1,"/")[[1]][1],"/","0",str_split(df$Col1,"/")[[1]][2])
df$check=str_detect(df$Col2,stringr::fixed(df$Col1))
df[which(df$check!=TRUE),]$Col1=df[which(df$check!=TRUE),]$Col3
df$check=str_detect(df$Col2,stringr::fixed(df$Col1))
df2<-df[which(df$check==TRUE),]
```

Currently the first line of code is only making the string calculations for the first row and repeating it down the rest of the dataframe.

The expected result would be:

```
Col1     Col2
CN234    CN234
WO/0123  WO/0123
```

Can anyone help me with this please?

Comment: What is the expected result for your sample dataset, please?

Comment: Hi, I've added the expected result to the original post.

Comment: Why is row 2 recoded but row 3 not ?

Comment: the final result is to keep rows that have values in Col1 that are present in Col2, but the KR 456 does not match the value in Col2. I had attempted to put a new column in (Col3) to recode all the values but only capture in Col1 those that have not already matched the values in Col2.

[/edit] sorry, misunderstood your question. Originally, filtering the data based on matches between Col1 and Col2 were thought to be sufficient, but we had discovered that there were some lines that required the additional zero instead. so it's a two step check.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, both columns match if

- the leading two letters are identical
- the trailing digits, i.e., the respective integer values, are identical.

This is what I would do with my preferred tools:

```
library(data.table)
library(magrittr)
library(stringr)

df <- fread("Col1     Col2 
CN234    CN234
WO/123   WO/0123
KR567    KR456")

df[str_extract(Col1, "^[[:alpha:]]{2}") == str_extract(Col2, "^[[:alpha:]]{2}") &
     str_extract(Col1, "\\d+$") %>% as.integer() == str_extract(Col2, "\\d+$") %>% as.integer()][
       , Col1 := Col2][]
```

> ```
>       Col1    Col2
> 1:   CN234   CN234
> 2: WO/0123 WO/0123
> ```

Here, the dataset is filtered first for rows who fulfill above criteria, and then the columns are copied.